# counting string in when using concat in sql

Tags: sql, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I have a problem with counting strings in my concat syntax.
i concat 4 columns and the result is as below.

(complete,complete,incomplete,incomplete).

now I want to score them base on the number of 'complete'. for example if there are 4 complete it is 100%, if there are 3 complete it is 60% and so on.
is there any way to do this in sql

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  And how is 60% calculated from 3 complete and 1 incomplete?  Also tag with the database you are really using -- and none else.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want aggregation like this:

```
select avg(case when val = 'complete' then 1.0 else 0 end) as complete_ratio
```